# Let $f:(0,1)\to (0,1)$ be a continuously differentiable function. Then which of the following are true?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> Let $f:(0,1)\to (0,1)$ be a continuously differentiable function. Then which of the following are true?
>   $1)$ $g=1/f$ is continuous function on $(0,1)$.
>   $2)$ $g=1/f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$.
>   $3)$ $g=1/f$ is uniformly continous on $(0,1)$.
>   $4)$ $h$ defined by $h(x)= x(1-x)f(x)$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$ is uniformly continuous.

---

I know third is false as if $f(x)=x$ then $g(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$.

Further I know the answers are 1),2),4)

How to prove these?

Answer (score 0):

For $1)$ and $2)$ you just need to cite the common theorems about continuous and differentiable functions, i.e. the quotient (whenever the denominator is non-zero, which is the case here by assumption) of continuous/differentiable functions is again continuous/differentiable. For $2)$ you should further compute the derivative and then notice that it is made up of continuous functions.

For $4)$ you should try to find a counterexample, something which approaches infinity at $x \to 0$ sup-linearly like $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: F(x)= x-(1/2) then 1/f=1/(x-1/2) not continuous at 1/2? I got struck here

Comment: Your $F$ is not a function $(0,1) \to (0,1)$....

Comment: ok got it thanks